# Javascript: count a single user's video plays on a page?

Tags: javascript, video, counter, increment

I've seen a lot of chatter here about counting total video views across users.  That's not what I need.

I'm developing a web-based experiment where users will see a video and then choose between 2 pictures.  They have the option to click on the video to replay it, and I simply want to track how many times they replay a given video before making their choice.  The script is designed such that the video can't be replayed until it ends, at which point a mouseclick will replay it from the beginning.

Attempt 1: using an event listener to increment a counter when onplay fires.
Problem 1: having the increment function inside the addeventlistener function was causing loop-like behavior.  Instead of incrementing once each time, the counter would increment a number of times equal to its current value.  Not ok.

Attempt 2: Take the increment statement/function out of the addlistener statement.
Problem 2: This produces nice incrementing, but it just counts the number of CLICKS, rather than the number of PLAYS.  For example, if a user doubleclicks, the counter will register that as "2", whereas the video will only play once in response.

I'm sure Attempt 1 was nearer the mark, so here's my code for that and perhaps someone can tell me why I'm getting such loopy results?  Pun intended.  This code displays both problems: it increments as if it's in a loop, and it counts clicks instead of plays.  The first is more mysterious to me, but I've had a harder time solving the second.  I'd be much obliged if any of you can solve both!

It's likely that part of my problem stems from the fact that I'm calling the PlayVideo() function via "onclick".  I'm open to other ways of setting that up to be less of a problem.

P.S.  I also don't want to count the number of times the video ends, since many users will likely make their choice before the end of a video. The increment needs to happen early on.

```
        function PlayVideo(){
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];          
        myVideo.play();
        myVideo.addEventListener('playing', function(){
            viewcounter++}, false);
        console.log(viewcounter);
        //myVideo.addEventListener('onplay', viewcounter++);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `playing` to `play`

```
function onPlay(){
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];          
    myVideo.play();
    myVideo.addEventListener('play', function(){
        viewcounter++}, false);
    console.log(viewcounter);
}
```

This will should be called whenever the video is played. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I've tried that and I get the exact same behavior.  :-\

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an *answer* so much as a workaround, but in case anyone out there is having similar issues:

I basically needed a way to suppress the increment function until the first click after the video finished playing.  To do that, I created an additional variable (named "fired"), and initialized it to false.  The increment function is called only if "fired" = false.  After it fires once, I set fired = true.  Then I use an event listener to set it back to false after the video has ended.  It's ugly, but it works.

If anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears!

```
var fired = false;

function PlayVideo(){
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];          
            myVideo.play();
            StartTimer();
            if (!fired) {
                viewcounter++; //in other words, increment the first time it's clicked, but then not again until after the variable has been reset to false, which happens at the end of the video.
            }
            fired = true;
            console.log(viewcounter);
            myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function(){fired=false;}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also count the number of times that the viewer passes a certain time-point (or add multiple time-point counters):

```
var triggerTime=1, fired=0;

function PlayVideo(){
myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
       var timer = myVideo.currentTime.toFixed(2) ;
       if (timer > triggerTime) {
            if (!fired) {
                viewcounter++;
                fired=true;
            }
       }
myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function(){fired=false;}, false);
}
```